# Select rows for last n days after event occurs

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table and data:

```
PatientID   PatientName   Diagnosed  ReportDate   ...
1                         0
1                         0
1                         0
1                         1
```

So there are multiple rows for each patient, as the reports come few times a day.
Whenever the diagnosed field is changed to 1, for that patient, I'd like to get the past 3 days of data . So when Diagnosed ==1, get report time -3 days of data for each patient.

```
SELECT Patients.ReportDate
FROM Patients 
WHERE Diagnosed = 1 and date > ReportDate - interval '3' day;
```

So getting the past 3 days of data, can be done with ReportDate - interval time, but how do I specify that for every patient (since multiple ids can be for that patient) based on the diagnosed field?

I usually do this filtering after getting csvs in python, but the data set is too large, so I'd like to filter before I convert them to dataframes.

Comment: Are there separate, related tables for patients and reports?

Comment: So I only have access to this Patients table, that receives frequent reports. And all data I should get, is from this one table. There is another Unique ID as field, since PatientID is repeated, but I only shared the columns relevant to the filtering.

Comment: Please show your version of Postgres (`SELECT version();`) and the actual table definition (for relevant columns) including the PK column, exact data types and constraints (`CREATE TABLE ...`) Can `Diagnosed` go back to `0` for the same `PatientID` (repeatedly)? If so, only report the latest episode?

Comment: Yes, it automatically receives reports, at set hours. The diagnosis are automated based on mobile sensor data. So if it's suspected to have an ailment, it will report a 1, otherwise it keeps reporting 0.
I do not have access on changing the way the data is populated. I just need to query and get the information of interest.
So every 6 hours, there is a report coming in for all patients in their system, with a yes or no for diagnosis. It can be repeating no no no, until he is suspected to be sick. That's why I need to query from the moment he was report as sick, to the last 3 days of data.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever the diagnosed field is changed to 1, for that patient, I'd like to get the past 3 days of data.

```sql
SELECT (p).*
FROM  (
   SELECT p
        , diagnosed
        , bool_or(diagnosed = 1) OVER (w RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND '3 days' FOLLOWING) AS in_range
        , lag(diagnosed) OVER w AS last_diagnosed
   FROM   patients p
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY patientid ORDER BY reportdate)
   ) sub
WHERE  diagnosed = 0 AND in_range
    OR diagnosed = 1 AND last_diagnosed = 0
ORDER  BY patientid, reportdate;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=48dfcbe94d9b6e90444340a5a8273545)*

Returns the "past 3 days of data" where the "field is changed to 1" (previous row had "0").

The `WINDOW` clause is just syntactic sugar to avoid spelling out the same window definition repeatedly. (No additional benefit for performance.)

`SELECT p` in the innermost subquery is a neat way to get the whole row. The outer `SELECT (p).*` returns complete rows without auxiliary columns added in the subquery. This way we get whole rows without spelling out all columns (or even needing to know all of them).

[`RANGE` ***`distance`*** `PRECEDING/FOLLOWING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) requires Postgres 11 or later.
Here is a slower alternative that also works for older versions:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM  (
   SELECT patientid, reportdate
   FROM  (
      SELECT patientid, reportdate, diagnosed
           , lag(diagnosed) OVER (PARTITION BY patientid ORDER BY reportdate) AS last_diagnosed
      FROM   patients
      ) p0
   WHERE  diagnosed = 1
   AND    last_diagnosed = 0
   ) d
JOIN   patients p USING (patientid)
WHERE  p.reportdate BETWEEN d.reportdate - interval '3 days' AND d.reportdate
ORDER  BY p.patientid, p.reportdate;
```

Subquery `d` select rows where `Diagnosed` just switched to `1`. Then self-join to select your time frame.

For [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) basics, see:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

You also added:

> So when Diagnosed ==1, get report time -3 days of data for each patient.

That's a wider definition, and that's what [Gordon's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69287354/939860) does. Goes to show the importance of an exact definition of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this another way, which is whether `diagnosed = 1` in the next three days -- and take all rows where that is true:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             count(*) filter (where diagnosed = 1) over (partition by patientId order by reportDate range between interval '0 day' following and interval '3 day' following) as cnt_diagnosed_3
      from patients p
     ) p
where cnt_diagnosed_3 > 0
order by patientId, reportDate;
```